# Which probability concept should be applied to this question?

Tags: probability

My friend takes 10 cards at random from a 52-card deck, and places them in a box. Then he puts the other 42 cards in a second, identical box. He hands me one of the two boxes and asks me to draw out the top card. What is the probability that the first card I draw will be the Ace of Spades?

Comment: ======== 1/52 :)

Comment: Great, can you please explain?

Comment: Every card is just as likely! That is, the card you draw is just as likely to be the ace of spades as that it is any of the other 52 cards.

Comment: The seperation of cards into inequal heaps is a complete distraction. $~$ There is no bias on the location of any of the cards; each of the fifty-two cards has the same chance to be the card you select from whichever box you were given.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the event that the Ace of Spades is selected from the box you take .

Let $B$ be the event that the Ace of Spades is *in* the box you take .

Let $C$ be the event that you take the box with $10$ cards .

Then by the Law of Total Probability :

$$\def\P{\operatorname{\sf P}}\P(A)~{=\P(A\mid B)\P(B) +\P(A\mid B^\complement)\P(B^\complement)\\= \P(A\mid B)\P(B) +0 \\ = \P(A\mid B,C)\P(B\mid C)\P(C)+\P(A\mid B,C^\complement)\P(B\mid C^\complement)\P(C^\complement) \\ = (\tfrac 1{10}\times\tfrac{10}{52}\times\mathsf P(C))+(\tfrac 1{42}\times\tfrac {42}{52}\times(1-\mathsf P(C)) \\ = ~\tfrac 1{52} }$$

Are you convinced that splitting the deck into two boxes is a distraction?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation that really helped me in grasping at grass-root level.

Answer (score 0):

The card you draw is just as likely to be the ace of spaces as that it is any of the other 51 cards ... So the chance of it being the ace of spades is $\frac{1}{52}$

Answer (score 0):

Probabilities are beliefs. The probability of drawing a particular card from 52-card deck is 1/52, and the manipulations of your friend do not provide any useful information to change this belief.